# Как создать websocket клиент на php

Tags: php, websocket

Нужно сделать вебсокет клиент на пхп для получения с **чужого** websocket сервера даных) Информации о серверах в интернете полно, о клиенте на php ничего не нашёл[.
Cмотрел стак](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160899/websocket-client-in-php), но адекватного решения там нет.

В RATCHET не нашёл примера поднятия клиента на пхп.

Цель - получение даных с wss://site.com/data

upd1: [Нашёл либу](https://github.com/arthurkushman/php-wss)

Comment: Это было так сложно https://packagist.org/?query=websocket

Comment: советую ratchet, нежели изобретать колёса, его доки тут: http://socketo.me/docs/

Comment: Можетя чего-то не понимаю, в ratchet нахожу вижу только использование сервера. Но не клиента

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример простого клиента. Его можно переписать уже под свои нужды:

```
<?php
$PORT = 6666;
$HOST = "127.0.0.1";

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
    or die("error: could not create socket\n");

$succ = socket_connect($sock, $HOST, $PORT)
    or die("error: could not connect to host\n"); 

echo "Connect [OK] \n";

$text = "Hello, world!";

socket_write($sock, $text . "\n", strlen($text) + 1)
    or die("error: failed to write to socket\n");

while(($reply = socket_read($sock, 10000, PHP_NORMAL_READ)) !== false) {
    echo $reply;
}

$text = "Соединение не разорвано. Можно продолжать обмениваться информацией.";

socket_write($sock, $text . "\n", strlen($text) + 1)
    or die("error: failed to write to socket\n");

?>
```